# Errors in results after saving model vs using directly from memory

Tags: pytorch, transformer, huggingface, llm, serialisation

I am trying to save a Fine Tuned model using `trainer.save_model()` but after I load the saved_model it just responds with the input back again and does not give any new output.

But, when I don't save the model and use the one with changed weights from FT from memory. It gives expected responses.  (Jupyter notebook)

Example Code:

```
model_name = "bigcode/starcoder"

packing = False
base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, device_map='auto', load_in_8bit =True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="/tmp/output",
    num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
    optim=optim,
    save_steps=save_steps,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    weight_decay=weight_decay,
    fp16=fp16,
    bf16=bf16,
    max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
    max_steps=max_steps,
    warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
    group_by_length=group_by_length,
    lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=25
)

# Set supervised fine-tuning parameters
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=base_model,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
    packing=packing,
)

trainer.train()

trainer.save_model('xxx')

def infer(model, ip):
    inputs = tokenizer.encode(ip, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
    outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_new_tokens=300, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
    return tokenizer.decode(outputs[0])
```

Not sure what the issue is as not being able to save model is a bottleneck and it also does not release memory used within FT. (Jupyter)